# Why $bgprofiles is undefine if I do not place the isset?

Tags: laravel

Here is my codes.  How to define $bgprofile correctly?  I wonder why $bgprofile undefine error appears if I do not place the isset.  Evenso, I do not get the picture collection appearing which except to see.  Any clue?  Below I posted my SettingController.php, Setting.blade.php and Routes.php .

SettingController.php

```
public function getBackgroundProfile(Request $request)
{
    $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $user = User::where('domain', $domain)->first();

    $bgprofiles = DB::table('user_bgprofile')->where('user_id', $user->id)->get();    

    return view('soulfy.setting', [
            'bgprofiles' => $bgprofiles,
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
}
```

Setting.blade.php

```
     <form action="{{URL::to('/home/theme')}}" method="post"> 
                                    <span class="setting-name">THEME</span>

                                    <!-- <form method="POST" action="/posts"> -->
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}  
                                    <span class="setting-value center">

                                    <select name="menu">
                                        <option value="">All</option>
                                        <option value="Handicraft">Handicraft</option>
                                        <option value="Farming">Farming</option>
                                        <option value="Services">Services</option>
                                        <option value="Tour & Travel">Tour & Travel</option>
                                        <option value="Trading">Trading</option>
                                        <option value="Fishery">Fishery</option>
                                        <option value="Lifestyle">Lifestyle</option>
                                        <option value="Music">Music</option>
                                        <option value="Property">Property</option>
                                        <option value="Hobby">Hobby</option>
                                        <option value="Politic">Politic</option>
                                    </select>


                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">                                        
                                    <br><br>

                                    </span>
                                    </form>

                                    <form action="{{ action('SettingController@SendPicture') }}" method="post">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                                    <table>
                                        @foreach ($themes->chunk(3) as $chunk)
                                            <tr>
                                            @foreach ($chunk as $theme)
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="{{url('/')}}/uploads/theme/{{$theme->pic_name}}.jpg" data-lightbox="image-gallery" data-title="{{$theme->pic_name}}" >
                                                    <img width="100px"
                                                        height="100px"
                                                        src="{{url('/')}}/uploads/theme/{{$theme->pic_name}}.jpg"/></a> 
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pic[{{$theme->pic_name}}]" value="{{$theme->pic_name}}"/>
                                                </td>
                                            @endforeach
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </table>

                                    @if ( $themes->currentPage() != 1)
                                    <a href="{!! $themes->previousPageUrl() !!}"> << </a>@endif

                                    {!! $themes->currentPage() !!} of {!! $themes->lastPage() !!}

                                     @if ( $themes->currentPage() !=  $themes->lastPage())
                                    <a href="{!! $themes->nextPageUrl() !!}"> >> </a>@endif


                                    <input type="submit" value="Purchase">  
                                    </form>


                                    <form action="{{ action('SettingController@getBackgroundProfile') }}" method="post">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                                    <table>
                                    @if(isset($bgprofile)) {

                                        @foreach ($bgprofiles->chunk(3) as $chunk)
                                            <tr>
                                            @foreach ($chunk as $bgprofile)
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="{{url('/')}}/uploads/bgprofile/{{$bgprofile->bgprofile}}.jpg" data-lightbox="image-gallery" data-title="{{$bgprofile->bgprofile}}" >
                                                    <img width="100px"
                                                        height="100px"
                                                        src="{{url('/')}}/uploads/bgprofile/{{$bgprofile->bgprofile}}.jpg"/></a> 
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="pic[{{$bgprofile->bgprofile}}]" value="{{$bgprofile->bgprofile}}"/>
                                                </td>
                                            @endforeach
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach

                                        }

                                    @endif 
                                    </table>



                                    </form>
```

routes.php

```
   Route::get('home/bgprofile', 'SettingController@getBackgroundProfile');
```

Comment: That seems fine, what is the problem? Do you get no output? Or is it just the images that aren't working?

Comment: How you passed `$themes` from `SettingController.php`? I think, it should `$bgprofiles`. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining `$bgprofile` in your `settings.blade.php` file? The variable you're passing to the view is `$bgprofiles` (plural), so if there's no definition anywhere - you're bound to be thrown an error unless you're adding the `isset` condition, in which case it'll see that it isn't defined and proceed no further.